# Get information from surfaceview in activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, surfaceview

I want to pass information(1 integer number) from surfaceview to activity, but throw intent and putextra i cant do this, throw surfaceview.fail i get 0. There is main peaces of code:

```
    public class Game extends SurfaceView {
    int fail=0;
    ...
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {  if (sch==3){

              Context context = getContext(); 
              Intent intent = new Intent(context, Single_result.class);

              context.startActivity(intent);}
fail+=1;
...(drawing)
```

int fail is increase after every frame, please, help, how i can get final value of fail in single_result class.

Comment: Please explain what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a listener interface

```
public interface GameCallback{
    public void onEvent(int i);
}
```

Let your activity implement GameCallback

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements GameCallback{...
```

You will get your integer from surface in onEvent() method of your Game activity

```
@Override
public void onEvent(int i){
    // handle your integer here
}
```

Add to your activity methods somewhere after your Game is created:

```
mGame.setGameCallback(this);
```

where mGame is your surfaceview

Add to your Game class:

```
private GameCallback mGameCallback;

public void setGameCallback(GameCallback cb){
    this.mGameCallback = cb;
}
```

When you want to send message to your activity add:

```
if(mGameCallback!=null){
    mGameCallback(someNumber);
}
```

That's it